# Modifying or Override value of a posted form field in symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a symfony 2 form that simply posts the comment. I want to remove html characters from the posted form before saving it to database. I read somewhere that you can't directly change the value of posted form and you need to create an event listener. I have created an event listener for this purpose to achieve this goal. So i created an event listener and below is the code.

```
<?php

// src/Adhl/FrontBundle/EventListener/StripHtmlSubscriber.php

namespace Adhl\FrontBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class StripHtmlSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event) {

        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        $event->getData()->setDetails(strip_tags($event->getData()->getDetails()));

        $form->add('details', 'textarea', array(
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'cols' => '30',
                'class' => 'text-input span8'
            )
                )
        );
    }
}
```

`$event->getData()->setDetails()` changes the value of posted field "details"

but `$event->getData()->getDetails()` does not returns anything.

I want to get the post field that has the name *"details"*, strip html tags from it and save it back to same posted key.

In simple PHP I could do it as:

```
$_POST['details'] = strip_tags($_POST['details']);
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your FormType class look like?
do you bind it on a entity or array?

If you do the entity binding, then simply in the entity modify the setDetails method in your entity to

```
setDetails($details) {
    $this->details = strip_tags($details);
}
```

if you have a array binding then in the action or subscriber the getData() will return an associatoive array not a entity

```
 $data = $event->getData();
 $data['details'] = strip_tags($data['details']);
 $event->setData($data);
```

Comment: I tried '$data['details'] = strip_tags($data['details']);' inside my event listener but i get this error: Cannot use object of type Adhl\CmsBundle\Entity\CommentEntity as array

Comment: @Salman  then just use the first part of code. in your CommentEntity. the second code was for a form, that is not Entity bound.